# Add marking to JSViz Visualization in Spotfire

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, spotfire

I am stuck on an issue where I need to add marking to D3 VennDiagram Visualization in Spotfire, I tried adding below code but it fails to execute marking:

Hi Team,

I am not able to add marking to VennDiagram or any other JSViz samples provided by TIBCO for D3.

You can download the DXP file from : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7rSzsao8vgUUlEyc0hWUk13WmM

I am using the following code to add marking, but it fails:

```
function markModel(markMode, rectangle) {
if (svg) {
    // No point in continuing if we don't have an svg object
    // Start collecting indexes of svg objects marked.
    var indicesToMark = [];
    var markData = {};
    markData.markMode = markMode;


    svgElem = svg[0][0];
    var rpos = svgElem.createSVGRect();
    rpos.x = rectangle.x;
    rpos.y = rectangle.y;
    rpos.height = rectangle.height; // + one to get the item under the click
    rpos.width = rectangle.width; // + one to get the item under the click
    var elements = svgElem.getIntersectionList(rpos, svgElem);
    for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index = index + 1) {
        if (elements[index].id) {
            indicesToMark.push(elements[index].id);
        }
    }

    markData.indexSet = indicesToMark;

    markIndices ( markData );
}
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this